# What type of programming language/software should I use to make games on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-4

For Christmas I received a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, and I have been looking at some projects to make with it. One that I was interested in the arcade machine project, but most projects suggest getting an emulator, which is illegal. I want to program my own games. When I look on the website for projects where you make games, it usually suggests Scratch or Python. I find Scratch too easy, and it isn't the best for making a good quality game. I have never used Python, but I have some experience using Java in Eclipse and C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio. I would like to make a 2D game with graphics. What type of programming and software should I use to program games for my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I would suggest Python3 and the pygame library. Google for loads of examples.

Comment: Welcome. Everybody and their uncle uses python on the pi, so you might as well too.  But opinions like that do not suit an objective Q&A format.  This is something you have to evaluate for yourself by asking more specific objective questions about the options -- "Can I do _____ in python?", "Which of these languages offers the best performance?", etc. -- note that most of those questions are probably off-topic here as there are no programming languages unique to the brand of hardware.  Also, you will probably find existing information online, so most of them do not really need to be asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole book full of examples (in python3) at: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/retro-gaming and some older stuff at: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/essentials-games-vol1

You'll also find lots of games in the back issues of *The MagPi Magazine* at: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/issues